# swiftで日付を変更する

Tags: swift, swift3

日付を変更するアプリを作成したいのですが以下のコードでエラー(signal SIGABRT)が出ます。
大変お手数ですがアドバイス頂けないでしょうか？

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Picture1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Pictureimage1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Date: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var WO: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Card: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SelectDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var but: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sub: UILabel!

    let nowDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
    let inputDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
        self.SelectDate.text = dateFormat.string(from: nowDate as Date)
        self.SelectDate.delegate = self

        inputDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        self.SelectDate.inputView = inputDatePicker

        let pickerToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:self.view.frame.size.height/6, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40.0))
        pickerToolBar.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height-20.0)
        pickerToolBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
        pickerToolBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        pickerToolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        let spaceBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace,target: self,action: Selector(("a:")))

        let toolBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .done, target: self, action: Selector(("toolBarBtnPush:")))

        pickerToolBar.items = [spaceBarBtn, toolBarBtn]
        self.SelectDate.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar
    }

        func toolBarBtnPush(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
            let pickerDate = inputDatePicker.date
            self.SelectDate.text = dateFormat.string(from: pickerDate as Date)

            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3より、セレクタの書式が変わりました。

```
let toolBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK",
    style: .done,
    target: self,
    action: Selector(("toolBarBtnPush:")))
```

*書式だけでなく、かっこがワンセット余計。*

この行の`Selector("toolBarBtnPush:")`は、こう変わります。

```
#selector(ViewController.toolBarBtnPush(sender:))
```

`ViewController`クラス内で指定するとき、`ViewController.`は、省略できます。（アクションメソッドが、どのクラスに定義されているか、明示しましょうと推奨されているので、クラス名を頭につけています。）

---

※本題と関係ありませんが、Swift 3より、型名`NSDate`は、`Date`に変更されましたから、統一したほうが、スッキリします。`as Date`というキャストが不用にもなります。